Can I build a query on my website that queries another website?
I want to build a website for my karaoke business where my customers can search for available songs. The website where this is done is Korean. I want to build a search field on my website that will query this remote site and spit the result back so that my users don't get confused by having to navigate in a foreign language.
The specific URL is ( https://www.tjmedia.com/tjsong/song_search.asp )
Is there any way users can search via my website, and on the backend the request goes to this remote site, and returned to the customer? I only have HTML and CSS experience, so I don't know if this is possible or not with scripting. Thank you for your responses.

If you do this, please get permission.

This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web development which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their FAQ before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does not meet their guidelines.
